# Is there a decidable algorithm to compose two well-behaved recursive functions that work on a recursive tree datatype?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, computability, programming-languages

Let the following datatype be defined:

```
 data T = A | B T | C T T
```

That is, `B, B T, B (B T), C A A, C (B T) A` and so on all are members of T. Now, suppose we define two functions that operate on that type:

```
f :: T -> T
f A = A
f (B x) = B (B (f x))

g :: T -> T
g A = A
g (B x) = B (B (B (g x)))
```

There are restrictions on the definition of `f` and `g`: first, recursive calls can only be applied directly to a subterm of one of the inputs (guaranteeing termination), and second, they can't use any datatype other than T on their bodies (consider T is the only existing type). In this case, we know that the following function:

```
h :: T -> T
h A = A
h (B x) = B (B (B (B (B (B (h x))))))
```

works as the composition `f . g`. My question is, is it possible/decidable to find the composition of `f` and `g` in this form - that is, without any reference to `f` and `g` themselves? What is the name of the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: What are we given?  Are we given the source code of `f` and `g`?  Only black-box access to `f` and `g`?  Are there further restrictions on the body of `f` and `g`, such as they cannot contain conditional statements?  Do you have any requirements on what form of `h` you will accept?

Comment: They can not contain conditional statements as the only datatype available is T (conditionals are generally functions on Bool). Imagine a very limited subset of Haskell. You have full access to the source of `f` and `g`. The requirement of `h` is that you don't have a reference to `f` and `g` itself, ie, it must be fully inlined - except if that is impossible in some cases. Then, for those cases, a reference to `f` and `g` is acceptable.

Comment: And if that is desirable, the problem I am trying to solve is exactly that of inlining/fusing two recursive functions on T. I know the problem is difficult for arbitrary recursive functions, but I don't know how hard it is for that kind of restricted, provably terminating functions. I didn't have many attempts as I don't know exactly what is the problem I am facing, but I tried two different things, reducing the problem to context-free-grammars, as you've seen, and blindly inserting `g` inside the body of `f` and watching if it fits. In some cases it does and the result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are sufficiently well-behaved, as in your example, you can express `f` and `g` as regular transducers for trees.  Then you can compute the composition of two such transducers, which will also be a regular transducer (I believe), and convert it back to a Haskell function.

Another approach: in some cases, simple `let`-substitution might suffice.  For instance, given your `f` and your `g`, we can identify their composition `fg` via the following sequence of steps.  We know `fg = f . g`, so plugging in the definition of `g`, we get:

```
fg A = f(g(A)) = f A
fg (B x) = f(g(B x)) = f(B (B (B (g x))))
```

Now plugging in the definition of `f`, we get:

```
fg A = A
fg (B x) = B (B f(B (B (g x))))
```

Continuing to plug in the definition of `f`, we get:

```
fg A = A
fg (B x) = B (B (B B( f(B (g x)))))
```

And plugging in the definition of `f` once more:

```
fg A = A
fg (B x) = B (B (B B( (B (B (f(g x))))))
```

which simplifies to

```
fg A = A
fg (B x) = B (B (B (B (B (B (fg x)))))
```

And now you have your desired recursive definition of their composition.  Notice that this is the same as the function `h` you wanted to get out.  As far as I know, there's no guarantee that this procedure will always work, but it is easy enough to apply.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried, DW, but it didn't work in some cases such as `f (B (B x)) = B (B x)` and `g (B (B (B x))) = B (B (B x)))`, where `h` should be `h (B (B (B (B (B (B x)))))) = B (B (B (B (B (B (h x)))))` (this is where the other question come from). After many manual attempts I decided to ask help as this is probably a known problem with a proper name I could research about. I guess "regular transducers" are the keywords I need, let me research now. Thank you. Edit: I can't upvote you with this account.

Comment: @dokkat, glad this helps.  I'm not clear on why simply plugging in doesn't work on that example, though.  To have a full definition of `f`, it needs to cover all possible cases of what the input looks like, so you need to specify the values of `f (B A)` and `f A` and `g (B (B A))` and `g (B A)` and `g A`; once you do that, I think you might be able to make plugging-in work, if you also apply a case split on `x` as many times as needed.

Comment: Hmm? I'm not sure what you mean...? [Take a look?](http://lpaste.net/103030)

Comment: @dokkat: About your lpaste: (1) Your f and g are not toal. (2) You have to perform a case split on x in order to inline g so that eventually you can inline f.

Comment: 1. Your definition of `f` is not complete.  What is `f (B A)`?  Your definition of `f` doesn't say.  We might need to have a complete definition of `f` and `g` for my technique to work.  I suggest you start by extending your definition of `f` and `g` to cover all cases.   2. The answer to your "Now what?" is to case-split.  Once you have a complete definition for `f`, you'll discover there are two cases, depending on whether `g x = A` or `g x = B y`.  To resolve which is the case, you can case-split on `x`, based upon which of the patterns in the definition of `g` is matched by `x`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the name of the problem I am trying to solve?

This is a form of supercompilation.

Comment: ...? Mind elaborating further?